# Lightning Page Refresh component erroring out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, error, refresh

We have a lightning page where a section is getting updated via a third party webservice. In order to show the updated values, we have a lightning component to refresh the page once the values are updated. However, this page is currently throwing the below error.

```
Uncaught Error in A$.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'reloadRecord' of undefined]
```

The code is given below.

## PageRefresh.cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="dataRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!v.recordId}" layoutType="FULL" targetFields="{!v.dataRecord}" targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}" recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordSaveError))}">
<div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordSaveError}</div>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

## PageRefreshController.js:

```
({
doInit: function(component,event,helper){
    component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true);
    //set time-out
    helper.setTimer(component);
},

    handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED")
    {
        component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord();
        // get the fields that are changed for this record
        var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
        // record is deleted and removed from the cache
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
    }
},
})
```

## PageRefreshHelper.js:

```
({
setTimer:  function(component){
var that = this;
window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
        component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord();
        that.setTimer(component);
    }),1000 //time after which the component reloads to check for any change in the record data
);
}
})
```

The same code works fine in the developer sandbox, but not in the QA sandbox.

Can someone help?

Comment: Usually when we write the code in unsupported format, then on the newer release those things breaks. Why do you have to call the `recordLoader` on init?

Comment: I agree that it might not be needed, but it should not be causing the issue, right?

Comment: It may cause that issue, afaik, there is no guarantee that `force:recordData` is loaded exactly on init, there could be a race condition.

Comment: So. What could be the fix?